# Memory leak/management advice (new array in method) (c++)

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks

I'm following a tutorial on youtube and tried to change the code by a bit in the file Input methods:

```
static std::string read_file(const char* filepath){
    FILE* file = fopen(filepath, "rt");     //read text file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long length = ftell(file);
    char* data = new char[length + 1];
    memset(data, 0, length + 1);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, 1, length, file);
    fclose(file);

    std::string result(data);
    delete[] data;
    return result;
}
```

This was the original code and it would be used in this context:

```
std::string vertSourceString = read_file(m_VertPath);
const char *source = vertSourceString.c_str();
```

So I thought "Why am I using String at all? I have to include it, and then I have to copy eveything to string so I can copy it again to a char*? So I tried this:

```
static char* read_file(const char* filepath){
    FILE* file = fopen(filepath, "rt");     //read text file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long length = ftell(file);
    char* data = new char[length + 1];
    memset(data, 0, length + 1);
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(data, 1, length, file);
    fclose(file);

    return data;
}
```

But this has a very obvious memory leak if I don't delete it:

```
char *c = read_file("src/shaders/basic.vert");
delete c;
```

So, is there any way to delete it in the method and still return a copy of it? 
Doesn't seem like good practice a method requiring a delete. 
Should I just go back to the previous implementation?

PS: I know c++ has a "easier" way of reading files (fstream) but from a small research (and I will admit, without any tests by my side) this way is usually faster

Comment: You would have been better off if your thought had been "Why am I using `char *` at all? I should just use `string` everywhere."

Comment: Sorry, should have stated I'm using it with OpenGL to read shaders and to use in: "void glShaderSource(GLuint shader,  GLsizei count, const GLchar **string, const GLint *length);" so I will need the char * sooner or later I think

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite this using [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), [std::ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream) and [std::ostringstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream) like this:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

static std::string read_file(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << std::ifstream(filepath, std::ios::binary).rdbuf();
    return oss.str();
}
```

Alternatively this method may be slightly more efficient (but less elegant) by cutting out the "middle man" (`std::ostringstream`):

```
static std::string read_file2(const std::string& filepath)
{
    std::ifstream ifs(filepath, std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate);

    std::string buf;
    buf.resize(ifs.tellg());
    ifs.seekg(0);

    if(ifs.read(&buf[0], buf.size()))
        return buf;

    return {};
}
```

**NOTE:** The second method here is the fastest method I tested out of 4 different methods using `std::ostringstream`, `std::FILE* fp = fopen()` & posix `int fd = open()`.

Comment: Wouldn't this fall to the original problem of using a string? which would mean string creation, then returning a copy of such string, and then copying the copied string into a char array?

Comment: @Sinn No, the string should not be copied at all. In the worst case the string should be *moved* in the return statement but *more likely* the entire operation will be *elided* by the compiler and the temporary returned by `oss.str()` will be constructed *in place* on the caller's stack..

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic memory allocation, is managed by the programmer in C++.
Then, the problem is, you can't unless you know the size of the file before hand, and allocate outside the method a buffer, and then pass it. 
Something like:

```
dosomething(file, file_size) {
char a[file_size]; //a is a pointer.
read_file(file, a);
}
```

Then in read_file:

```
/* Where a is char * parameter */
memset(a, 0, length + 1);
fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
fread(a, 1, length, file);
```

By doing something like this, you don't have to manually deallocate the memory for the char contents, since its stack memory, and it gets automaticly deallocated when the scope is exited.

Then again, this approach, would need you to know the file size before hand.

Comment: BTW, you could allocate  a huge buffer, if you knew the file size would never be greater than certain value.

Comment: Thanks for the alternatives but It really does seem my best bet is staying with string and just use "c_ctr()" in case I need the "char *". At least that way I don't have to worry about either getting the size earlier or deleting it after